# Can a Generic Java Static Method infer the return type during assignment

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

Currently I have a generic static method that takes in a Class as a parameter to infer the return type:

```
public static <T> T toObject(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(json, clazz);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you can guess, the way I use it looks like this:

```
MyObject obj = Converter.toObject(json, MyObject.class);
```

The way I see it, the type can be infered at runtime.

How do I modify my method to do this instead?

```
MyObject obj = Converter.toObject(json);
```

Is this even possible in Java?

Comment: No, it is not possible. Internally, `toObject` cannot guess the type `T`. You need external information in the form of `clazz`.

Comment: I think it's impossible because in the definition of your method there is no `Class` presented. So how it must understand to which class convert `json`?

Comment: "The way I see it, the type can be infered at runtime." No. "Inference" is purely at compile time. After type erasure, `T` doesn't exist.